# Javascript - Read input from number field, perform calculation, output result

Tags: javascript

I'm a total beginner at javascript, just looking for some help on getting this basic problem to work.  I want to take a Fahrenheit temperature number from a field, convert it to celsius, then output the result.  nothing is happening on button click.

HTML:

```js
    function myFunction() {
     var t0 = document.getElementById('temp1').value;
     t0 = (t0-32)*.5556;
     var t1 = document.getElementById('temp2').value;
     t1 = (t1-32)*.5556;
     var t2 = document.getElementById('temp3').value;
     t2 = (t2-32)*.5556;
     var t3 = document.getElementById('temp4').value;
     t3 = (t3-32)*.5556;
     var t4 = document.getElementById('temp5').value;
     t4 = (t4-32)*.5556;
     var text = "Temp 1: " + t0 + "<br>";
     text += "Temp 2: " + t1 + "<br>";
     text += "Temp 3: " + t2 + "<br>";
     text += "Temp 4: " + t3 + "<br>";
     text += "Temp 5: " + t4 + "<br>";
     document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = text;
    }
```

```html
<div align="center">

<form id="form2" action="/action_page.php">
  <label>Temp 1: </label><input class="field" type="number" id="temp1" 
name="temp1" /><br>
  <label>Temp 2: </label><input class="field" type="number" id="temp2" 
name="temp2" /><br>
  <label>Temp 3: </label><input class="field" type="number" id="temp3" 
name="temp3" /><br>
  <label>Temp 4: </label><input class="field" type="number" id="temp4" 
name="temp4" /><br>
  <label>Temp 5: </label><input class="field" type="number" id="temp5" 
name="temp5" /><br><br>
</form>
<p>Click the button to convert from Farenheit to Celsius</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>
<p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a typo on the `document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = text;` the `ID` is wrong, use it as `document.getElementById` JS is case-sensitive

Comment: Good catch,  I did fix this, sadly it's still not functional @CalvinNunes  Is it possible something else is broken?

Comment: are you sure? running your script with this type fixed, it showed the result

Comment: I even deleted my cache to make sure I wasn't running an old version of the page.  no change as far as output goes

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your Dev Tools console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides fixing the typo with the `ID`, changing to `Id`,
I really believe it's just the way you wrote your code. Make sure you place your script inside `head` tag. Here is a jsfiddle example with load type inside `head` : https://jsfiddle.net/56eet52k/9/

Comment: Wow that was it.  I wouldn't have caught that.  Strange, I had another javascript I worked on where it functioned in the body section of the HTML.  But switching it into the head portion was correct.  THANK YOU

Comment: to avoid that kind of problem, you need to make sure that all elements are already loaded in the DOM when calling a JS function. The best and more efficient way of doing this, is using jQuery plugin and putting your entire javascript inside this function: `$(document).ready(function() {all code here});` with that, you can load your script in any place you want, it will only run after everything is loaded

Comment: This means you have to use JQuery. The question was about javascript only.

Comment: Yep, I still haven't started to use JQuery yet, so Mojo's answer was perfect for my current work.  Thanks to both of you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = text;
You have a typo so correct above line to like this
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: as this is just a typo mistake, don't need to an aswer, just a comment is sufficient